# ImportError After Moving App to Nested Folder

Tags: django

My application was working fine when I wanted to see whether I could organize my project in a better way. I read through this tutorial [on structuring a django project](http://www.deploydjango.com/django_project_structure/index.html).

Before my project structure was as follows:

- camucamu

  - books

    - admin.py
    - models.py
    - views.py
    - __init__.py
  - static
  - templates
  - urls.py
  - views.py
  - settings.py
  - wsgi.py
  - __init__.py

What I wanted to do was move the books app into an apps folder. Thus I did that and changed the project structure to the following:

- camucamu

  - apps

    - books

      - admin.py
      - models.py
      - views.py
      - __init__.py
  - static
  - templates
  - urls.py
  - views.py
  - settings.py
  - wsgi.py
  - __init__.py

I then changed the imports in views.py and admin.py 
from books.models to apps.books.models. 
I also changed `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py from books to apps.books.

When I then tried to run syncdb, I get the following error:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError apps.books: No module named apps.books
```

What am I messing up here so it can't find my app anymore?

Comment: did you change the path in `manage.py`?

Comment: @Ahsan Why would I need to do that? The manage.py file just references the settings file which is still in the same place

Answer (score 4):

Your apps folder does not have an `__init__.py` file so it cannot be recognized as a python module

Comment: Good point, although I did just add an \__init__.py file to the apps folder and still get the same error.

Comment: If it is not the django dev server, restarting it could help but I am still wondering why syncdb would refuse to work

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error, following the same guide, as the last point of the following list was not cited. Make sure you performed the following changes:

- Create a blank `__init__.py` file inside the apps folder (needed for python to recognize it as a package)
- Update the import statements wherever you refer to an external app:

  ```
  from projectname.apps.appname.models import YourModel, YourOtherModel
  ```
- Inside `settings.py` edit `INSTALLED_APPS` such that it looks like this:

  ```
  INSTALLED_APPS = (

      ...

      # apps
      'projectname.apps.appname1',
      'projectname.apps.appname2',
  )
  ```
- **This one is not specified in the guide:** In all your `urls.py` files, update the `urlpatterns`!

  BEFORE:

  ```
  # client views
  urlpatterns += patterns('appname',
      ...
  )
  ```

  AFTER:

  ```
  # client views
  urlpatterns += patterns('projectname.apps.appname',
      ...
  )
  ```
- Finally remember to update your changes by calling `python manage.py syncdb`

Hope that helped.